# Adding to a Treeset in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, treeset

I am having an issue trying to create add points to a separate branch of the TreeSet. Currently, when my for condition is satisfied, it is adding points to the TreeSet one by one but considering each as an individual TreeSet.

E.g. xCoords contains [29.33]

[29.33, 30.12]

[29.33, 30.12, 31.23]

Once it has gone through the entire loop, it has added all the point to a single TreeSet. This is not what I want as the TreeSet should be created through a cluster assignment which is defined as x in my case.

I am hoping to get the TreeSet to contain all the points that are equal to the same X into the same TreeSet and all the differing X values into their own respective TreeSets. What should I do to accomplish this?

```
      double slope = lineData[0];
                TreeSet<Double> xCoords = new TreeSet<Double>();


                for (int l = 0; l < dataarray.size(); l++){

                    System.out.println("This is point number " + l);


                        if (index >= dataarray.size()) break; 
                        for (int x = 0; x < clusters.size(); x++){
                        if (dataarray.get(l).getCluster() == x){
                            xCoords.add((double)dataarray.get(l).getTemperature()); 
                            //System.out.println("This is the Cluster number " + x);
                            //System.out.println("This is the associated Temperature value " + dataarray.get(l).getTemperature());
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println();


                System.out.println("This is xCoords");
                System.out.println(xCoords);


                double xleft = xCoords.first();
                double xright = xCoords.last();

                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to open data files");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: ...it is not even a little bit clear what you want this to be doing.  What is a cluster?  What would it mean for a "TreeSet to be created through a cluster assignment"?

Comment: Also what is a "separate branch" of a `TreeSet`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The Cluster assignment is a number I attach to a group of points that share a certain distance between them. This number is currently represented through the x variable as my cluster currently goes through number 0 to 3 currently. The wording of separate branch of a TreeSet was incorrect. I mean to create a group of TreeSets which is based on the Cluster number I assign to it in which one group holds points sharing cluster number 1 and the next one holds points sharing cluster number 2.